# Vim filetype if statement not working

Tags: vim, file-type

In my ~/.vimrc, I have an if statement that is supposed to determine if the open file is a python file or not:

```
if (&ft=='python')
    map <F9> <esc>:w<enter>:!python3 '%'<enter>
endif
```

The goal is to bind the python execution command to F9 if the file is a python file, but when I press F9 in a .py file nothing happens.  I took out the if statement, and it worked.  What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that instead:

```
au FileType python map <buffer> <F9> <esc>:w<bar>!python3 '%'<cr>
```

Your `.vimrc` config file runs only once on startup. So if you put an `if` test at this time, it won't work, because no python file is then currently edited.

But you can use `.vimrc` to setup an *automatic* behaviour : something that `vim` will do each time it will encounter a special condition. The condition can be in your case : "A new file is being editing, and its file type is 'python'". See `:h :au`

In cases like yours, it's useful to add the `<buffer>` parameter in the `:map` command : it limits the scope of your mapping to the current buffer only : so when you will press <kbd>F9</kbd> on a non-python buffer, the mapping will not be trigerred.

EDIT:
In my first answer, I also deleted the `<esc>` in your command, **but** maybe I'm wrong about this, because it can cause problems in visual mode, so I put it again. You have to test it in visual mode, I didn't do it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  But do you know what was wrong with my version?